What is the correct way to deploy a nest js app in a azure web app server? Should the package.json be included?
The nest js build it's not including the package.json which seems to be normal, but then when deploying to azure web app, the server it was not capable to install the needed packages. Finally I have uploaded manually the package.json file and installed manually the dependencies, but I am sure this is not the way to do it. What is the correct way to deploy a nest.js app?
I deployed my dist folder as generated from the build and I expected the azure web app to be able to start my app without further manual workarounds.

How are you deploying your NestJS app to Azure Web Apps—using GitHub or VS Code?

I am using VS Code

Please check if the solution below helped you. Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with.

I created Sample nestjs App and deployed to the Azure web app (Linux) through VS code.
Thanks @Azure OSS Developer Support for Clear Explanation.

When you deploy the nestjs app to azure, the dist  folder and package.json are needed, So Entire Project needs to deploy.

Below is My complete Project Structure.


This is because Azure Web App needs the package.json file to know which dependencies to install. Without package.json, which leads to runtime errors.

The Nest project created listens on port 3000 by default. But in Azure Web App dynamically assigns a port number to application at runtime. This port is provided via the PORT environment variable.



So, I define the port in main.ts file as shown below.
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

Below is the complete code.
main.ts:
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  await app.listen(port);
}
bootstrap();

Make sure to add the start script to the package.json as shown below.
"start:prod": "node dist/main"

In VS code select Angular Extension -> Subscription -> Azure Web App -> Deploy to Web App -> Complete Project Folder as shown below.

It is Successfully deployed to Azure Web app.

Azure Web App Output:


Hi Aslesha and thanks for the answer, this was the confirmation I needed, so running a npm run build is useless when deploying to Azure in this case, you have to deploy the whole solution. This is what I did anyway but I thought it's not correct and should be another way to do it better, but it looks like this is the final solution. Thanks

@Maria Gavrila Thank you for your feedback, as it is best practice to build the application before deploying it to production, so I ran the npm run build command.
